# difference between getch() and (*getch)()

Tags: c++

I want to know the difference between these two statements....

1. ch=getch();
2. ch=(*getch)();

both statements return the same vale in "ch". I am possibly wrong but I think the second statement is used when we want to speed up the execution of the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### They do exactly the same thing.

There's no difference whatsoever.

Comment: thanks mehrdad....but I want to know that when we write firmware then which statement execute faster and why?

Comment: @Ricky - There's _absolutely_ no difference. The compiler will produce the same code in both cases. Use the first one because it's clearer. (Besides, you can't do a lot to speed up an operation that is dependent on keyboard input.)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that `getch()` is implemented as a macro (in addition to its implementation as an actual function).  If so,

```
ch=getch();
```

will invoke the macro, and

```
(*getch)()
```

will bypass the macro definition and call the actual function.  In that case, `getch()` is likely to be faster.

And in practice, at least for the implementations I've tried, `getch()` *isn't* implemented as a macro, and the two versions are identical.

In either case, `(*getch)()` is obfuscation for no good reason.